# How to upload Java JNLP file to server?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, jnlp

I studing to build JNLP file with Netbeans from http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jws.html and I want to upload JNLP file to server , but I'm not sure JNLP file can use with tomcat or glassfish only, or can use with another server. So I paste all file form dis folder in my project to www folder in apache appserv. but when I click Lunch button it show this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Basic Application Example</title>
        <vendor>Sun Microsystems Inc.</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://appframework.dev.java.net"/>
        <description>A simple java desktop application based on Swing Application Framework</description>
        <description kind="short">Basic Application Example</description>


    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="test_app.jar" main="true"/>


    <jar href="lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/gdata-calendar-2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/gdata-client-1.0.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="test_app.Test_appApp">

    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: I wish I had a "Lunch" button, sounds delicious! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to Add the following entries to the configuration file:

```
AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file .jnlp
AddType application/x-java-archive .jar
AddType application/x-java-archive-diff .jardiff
```

On Debian flavors, this file is at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but your distribution may be different. See more at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout.

Comment: I Add these entries

`AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file .jnlp
AddType application/x-java-archive .jar
AddType application/x-java-archive-diff .jardiff` under these entries 
`AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^` but it show same response. It show xml code. It not run jnlp.

Comment: You need to contact your service provider (I mean you hosting provider). I had that problem too on one of my hosts sometimes ago, They know what to do.